# How can I create a sequence in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, sequence, series

I know there is a function in R to create a sequence, but is not working for exactly what I want.

I have a data frame which size is going to change every time I run my code. This is my data frame

```
 pais   cum_cases  time_cases  
 MX        1            1
 MX        4            2
 MX        5            6
....
```

I want to replace the values of the column **cum_cases** with a serie that double the values. 
Example
I really don´t care what values are in the column **cum_Cases I want to replace wit double values starting of specific value. 
Example, if I want to start with the value **10** all the next values of the columns must be replaced by

```
cum_cases
  10
  20
  40
  80
  160
  320
... Until the last row of my data frame
```

Example 2.
x -> 6

```
cum_cases
  6
  12
  24
  48
  96
  192
... Until the last row of my data frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cumprod` in combination with `rep` to produce a doubling sequence.

```
(x$cum_cases <- 10 * cumprod(c(1, rep(2, nrow(x)-1))))
#[1] 10 20 40

(x$cum_cases <- 6 * cumprod(c(1, rep(2, nrow(x)-1))))
#[1]  6 12 24
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(pais="MX", cum_cases=c(1,4,5), time_cases=c(1,2,6))
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply the start value (first row) by 2 to the power of `rowid - 1` as the value doubles with every row. A way to do this with `dplyr` is:

```
df <- data.frame(time_cases = c(1, 2, 6, 10, 11, 15), cum_cases = 6)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(cum_cases = cum_cases[1] * 2 ^ (rowid - 1)) %>% 
  select(-rowid)

  time_cases cum_cases
1          1         6
2          2        12
3          6        24
4         10        48
5         11        96
6         15       192
```

I first create a `rowid` by `tibble::rowid_to_column()` and afterwards delete it again.